# How to change layoutManger for lazyColoumn in jetpack compose(vertical ,horizontal ,grid)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change `LayoutManger`(I don't know what that is called in jetpack compose) for `LazyColumn` so I can make the items scroll horizontally or vertically or in grid.

Answer (score 4):

With `1.0.0` you can use:

- [**`LazyColumn`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazycolumn) : produces a vertically scrolling list
- [**`LazyRow`**:](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazyrow)  produces a horizontally scrolling list

Something like:

```
LazyColumn {    
   items((1..1000).toList()) {
            Text(text = "Item $it")
        }
}
```

- the [**`LazyVerticalGrid`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#lazyverticalgrid) provides experimental support for displaying items in a grid.

Something like:

```
val numbers = (0..20).toList()

LazyVerticalGrid(
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(4)
) {
    items(numbers) {
        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Text(text = "Number")
            Text(text = "  $it",)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Jetpack Compose you can use `LazyRow` for horizontal scroll. `LazyVerticalGrid` can be used for `Grid`, which is still an experimental API. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#grids).
[This](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists) for complete details about lists.
Official Jetpack Compose [samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples)